# Where does IE8 save the RSS feeds in Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, feed

I would like to export-backup the RSS feeds I have aggregated in internet explorer, but I can't find them, which would be the first step in the process. Any idea where they are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSS feeds are now integrated to Windows and Internet Explorer simply is a program that can access them.

The actual location for the RSS feeds are:

> C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Feeds

Comment: Duh, I would have expected them to be on Roaming, not Local.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to export and backup RSS feeds, I would follow the steps under the section "To export RSS feeds from Internet Explorer 8" from this page: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Import-and-export-RSS-feeds-in-Internet-Explorer